# If statement if variable for string does not exist...?

Tags: php

how would I write an `IF` statement that says if `$req` does not blank and equals string that does not exist then load, `load_template(tpl_path.'err404.tpl');` so if `$req` does not match or equal something that is valid then show error page.

```
if ($req == '')              load_template(tpl_path.'index.tpl');
if ($req == 'dologin')      include 'includes/dologin.php';
```

Comment: What is a string that doesn't exist for you? That sounds more philosophical than an actual problem statement to me.

Comment: ?? maybe you are asking for isset? `if (!isset($req) || $req == '') { ... } elseif ($req == 'do') { ... }` ?

Comment: How will $req be equal to string that does not exists?

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is `elseif` and `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [switch](http://php.net/switch) statement:

```
switch($req) {
  case '':
    load_template(tpl_path.'index.tpl');
    break;
  case 'dologin':
    include 'includes/dologin.php';
    break;
  default:
    load_template(tpl_path.'err404.tpl');
}
```

Comment: How does it check `does not exist` part?

Comment: @peipst9lker, And where is that on the answer?

Comment: Starx, I assume that "does not exist" mean something like "if it doesn't match anything else". The question never talks about that `$req` itself doesn't exist, just that its value is a non-blank string that "does not exist".

Comment: @peipst9lker and Starx I think acctman is just asking us to tell him how to use simple `else` in if else or `default` in switch case... so the answer is perfect for him.

Comment: @micha, I am bad at guessing problems

Comment: $req is just a variable that pulls the correct template file. ex: site.com/?req=dologin in which will display the login page. if a user type site.com/?req=dologin123 nothing will show because that template does not exist. in cases like that I want the err404.tpl to be displayed.

Comment: You could switch to `switch` :) or you could simply change your `if` statements to `elseif`s (and a final `else` displaying the 404): `if (nothing) default-page elseif (something) some-page elseif (anotherthing) another-page else 404-page`

Comment: @peipst9lker there would be a lot of else statements if I did that, I thought there would be a short one line way of doing it. i'll try the switch statement

Comment: if you just insert if (!isset($req)) { load index... } above the switch youre fine

Comment: I *guess* that they mean something like »Take `$req` and look if it matches a `.tpl` file in the file system. If so, then include it, otherwise throw 404.« Hardcoding the possible choices is easier than solving the possible security problems though, at least for a small number of choices. **EDIT** Oh, nevermind, they said that already. But didn't update the question.